# Espresso - Click item inside a nested recyclerview

Tags: java, android-espresso

So, I have a recyclerview inside a recyclerview. What I wanna do is click the image inside the first item (at position 0) in the child recyclerview. How am i gonna do that? Nothing works in every answer. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please share some relevant code so we can see what you've tried, and where you're getting stuck?

Comment: Hi Matt U, Thank you for answering my question. So actually figured it out. I posted my work around answer below.

Comment: And now Where I'm stuck is I cannot Scroll inside the Child Recyclerview. This is what I' doing to Scroll inside the Child Recyclerview:

//I want to scroll to position 4 inside the child recyclerview that is in the position 1 of the Parent recyclerview

onView(withId(PARENT_RECYCLERVIEW_ID)).perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(1, actionOnItemAtPosition(4, scrollTo())));

But this gives me error: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView  

And found that the child recyclerview is inside a LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

> So, I have a recyclerview inside a recyclerview. What I wanna do is click the image inside the first item (at position 0) in the child recyclerview.

Consulting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/lists#recycler-view-list-items) we see there are a few options.

So you want to perform an action on the main recycler. And that action is to perform another recycler view action on a child recycler. And *that* action it to click an image. In Espresso terms, that translates to something like:

```
// Starting from the bottom up, you want to click on the image
val clickOnImage = actionOnItem(withId(R.id.image_view), click())

// Next you want to do the above click action on the specific view in the child recycler
val clickOnImageOnChildRecycler = actionOnItemAtPosition(0, clickOnImage)

// Next you want to do the above on the specific child recycler
val clickOnChildReycler = actionOnItemAtPosition(INDEX_OF_CHILD_RECYCLER, clickOnImageOnChildRecycler)

// Finally, you want to do the clicking of a child on the main recycler
onView(withId(R.id.parent_recycler_view)).perform(clickOnChildReycler)
```

Then you can simplify and inline:

```
onView(withId(R.id.parent_recycler_view)) // On the parent recycler ...
    .perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(INDEX_OF_CHILD_RECYCLER, // On the specific child recycler ...
        actionOnItemAtPosition(0, // On the first item ...
            actionOnItem(withId(R.id.image_view), click()))) // Click the image ...
```

Should go without saying that I did not test this, but hopefully it works or at least sets you on the right path.

Comment: Hi dominicoder! Thank you for answering my question. I really appreciate it. I actually tried your answer but that gave me a — java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

But I actually figured out a work around to do it: 
I'll Post it in the Answer Portion.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

//Scroll to the 2nd Position of Parent Recyclerview
onView(withId(PARENT_RECYCLERVIEW_ID)).perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(1, scrollTo()));

//Added this line Just to make sure I'm already in the Child Recyclerview
onView(withId(PARENT_RECYCLERVIEW_ID)).perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(1, CustomViewAction.clickChildViewWithId(CHILD_RECYCLERVIEW_ID)));

//Click the Image inside the first item in the child recyclerview

onView(allOf(withId(CHILD_RECYCLERVIEW_ID), withParent(withRecyclerView(PARENT_RECYCLERVIEW_ID).atPosition(1)))).perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));